# How do I track the duration users spend on each controller or action?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to asp.net mvc, I want to track the duration each user spends on a controller or actionResult. That is how long they stay on a particular part of the web app e.g how long they spend surfing http://mywebappname/Resident/Index. This is what I've done so far...

```
 public class AuditAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected DateTime StarTime;
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        StarTime = DateTime.Now;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext executedContext)
    {
        // Stores the Request in an Accessible object
        var request = executedContext.HttpContext.Request;

        RouteData routeData = executedContext.RouteData;
        // Generate an audit
        Audit audit = new Audit()
        {
            // Your Audit Identifier     
            AuditId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            // Our Username (if available)
            UserName = (request.IsAuthenticated) ? executedContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name : "Anonymous",
            // The IP Address of the Request
            IPAddress = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? request.UserHostAddress,
            // The URL that was accessed
            ExactAreaAccessed = request.RawUrl,
            // Creates our Timestamp
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,

            ControllerAccessed = (string)routeData.Values["controller"],

            ActionAccessed = (string)routeData.Values["action"],

            Duration = (DateTime.Now - StarTime),

            DateCreated = DateTime.Now
        };

        // Stores the Audit in the Database
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        context.Audits.Add(audit);
        context.SaveChanges();

        // Finishes executing the Action as normal 
        base.OnResultExecuted(executedContext);
    }
}
```

but it is not giving me the expected result. Please what am I missing?

Comment: What you are measuring now is how long it takes for server to generate that page, not how much time user spent looking at it. To measure that you need to do that from client side (with javascript).

Comment: Ok. Thanks....any idea how I can achieve that using javascript?...I will really appreicate a code snippet. Thanks @evk

Comment: The easiest way is probably to pass forth and back parameters with the timestamps. One when the server finished generating the page and one with the next click calling the next action (doesn't work when the user leaves the server, of course)

Comment: You can try using a library such as Google Analytics that is specifically made to track things like this. You just need to create an account and include the javascript reference in your html. Otherwise you will have to implement something similar to what Markus mentioned.